# What code should be written for the movement of the sprite in CharacterBody2D if there is already written such code for the joystick:

Tags: godot, godot4

What code should be written for the movement of the sprite in CharacterBody2D if there is already written such code for the joystick:
"

```
@tool
extends TouchScreenButton

@export_range(0.0,1.0) var inner_opacity : float = 0.9
@export_range(0.0,1.0) var outer_opacity : float = 0.5

var direction : Vector2 = Vector2(0,0)
var strength : float = 0.0
var was_pressed : bool = false
var button_index : int = -1
var held : bool = false

@onready var half_width := self.texture_normal.get_width()/2
@onready var half_height := self.texture_normal.get_height()/2
@onready var inner_joystick_image : Sprite2D = $inner
@onready var radius :float = 75.0


signal joystick_input
signal joystick_released

func _ready():
    inner_joystick_image.position = Vector2(half_width,half_height)
    self_modulate = Color(1,1,1,outer_opacity)  
    $inner.modulate = Color(1,1,1,inner_opacity)
    $inner.position = Vector2(half_width,half_height)
    if shape is CircleShape2D:
        radius = shape.radius


func _input(event):
    if not event is InputEventScreenTouch and not event is InputEventScreenDrag: # Not a touch
        return

    if button_index != -1 and button_index != event.index: # No index, or index 
        return
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch and event.pressed == false:
        inner_joystick_image.global_position = global_position + Vector2(half_width,half_height)
        button_index = -1
        emit_signal("joystick_input", 0, Vector2(0,0), 0)
        emit_signal("joystick_released")
        held = false
        return
    if is_pressed(): # Button still in pressed state
        strength = event.position.distance_to(global_position+Vector2(half_width,half_height))
        if strength <= radius:
            button_index = event.index
        if button_index != event.index:
            return
        strength = smoothstep(0,radius,strength)
        direction = event.position.direction_to(global_position+Vector2(half_width,half_height)) * -1
        inner_joystick_image.global_position = clamp_to_circle(global_position+Vector2(half_width,half_height), radius, event.position)
        get_viewport().set_input_as_handled()
        held = true


func clamp_to_circle(point: Vector2, radius: float, value: Vector2) -> Vector2:
    var direction = value - point
    if direction.length_squared() > radius * radius:
        direction = direction.normalized() * radius
    return point + direction
    
func _process(delta):
    if held:
        emit_signal("joystick_input", strength, direction, delta)
```

Please help me
Please help me
Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Please help me

Comment: Spamming "Please help me" over and over really isn't going to get many people to answer. I understand it was to get around the "this question is mostly code" flag, but you need to provide more details. What have you tried?

It looks like the code is emitting a signal each frame that has input data. You most likely need to attach a script to your CharacterBody2D and listen for and respond to that signal.

Answer (score 2):

You'll most likely want to move the CharacterBody2D itself, not the Sprite2D. To do this, the best way is probably in the physics process loop.

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    move_and_collide(direction * strength * delta)
```

Comment: This code does not work. I wrote the following code:<func _physics_process(delta):
 if InputEventScreenTouch and InputEventScreenDrag:
  if direction == Vector2(1, 0):
   position.x += speed * delta
  elif direction == Vector2(-1, 0):
   position.x -= speed * delta
  elif direction == Vector2(0, 1):
   position.y += speed * delta
  elif direction == Vector2(0, -1):
   position.y -= speed * delta
 pass> but it doesn't work either